# Работа с Button Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, button

Можно ли как-нибудь вывести в консоль информацию из **`3`** текстовых полей по отдельности при нажатии привязанных к ним кнопок?

Я сам пытался, но почему-то все кнопки первые две кнопки срабатывают только к третьему текстовому окну, как это исправить? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот сам код:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Default')
window.minsize(width=200, height=200)

head = Label(window, text='')
head.pack()

head = Label(window, text='Введите текст')
head.pack()
b = StringVar()

def introductory_part():
    result1=textExample.get("1.0","end")
    print(result1)

def descriptive_part():
    result2=textExample.get("1.0","end")
    print(result2)

def result_part():
    result3=textExample.get("1.0","end")
    print(result3)

#Вводная часть
frame_top = LabelFrame(text="Укажите данные о себе")
frame_top.pack()
textExample=tkinter.Text(frame_top, height=5)
textExample.pack()
btnRead1=tkinter.Button(frame_top, height=1, width=10, text="Отправить", 
                    command=result_part)


# Описательная часть
frame_top = LabelFrame(text="Расскажите о своем опыте работы")
frame_top.pack()
textExample=tkinter.Text(frame_top, height=5)
textExample.pack()
btnRead2=tkinter.Button(frame_top, height=1, width=10, text="Отправить", 
                    command=result_part)


# Резолютивная часть
frame_top = LabelFrame(text="Укажите свои лучшие качества")
frame_top.pack()
textExample=tkinter.Text(frame_top, height=5)
textExample.pack()
btnRead3=tkinter.Button(frame_top, height=1, width=10, text="Отправить", 
                    command=result_part)

btnRead1.pack()
btnRead2.pack()
btnRead3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пока код не запускается выдает ошибки, исправьте.

Comment: @СергейКох, Исправил!

Comment: Вам все-таки надо определиться как импортировать модуль tkinter. А так пока вижу вызов одной функции всеми тремя кнопками.

Comment: А как это можно исправить?

Comment: А вы как думаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Default')
window.minsize(width=200, height=200)

head = Label(window, text='')
head.pack()

head = Label(window, text='Введите текст')
head.pack()
b = StringVar()

def introductory_part():
    result1=textExample1.get("1.0","end")
    print(result1)

def descriptive_part():
    result2=textExample2.get("1.0","end")
    print(result2)

def result_part():
    result3=textExample3.get("1.0","end")
    print(result3)

#Вводная часть
frame_top = LabelFrame(text="Укажите данные о себе")
frame_top.pack()
textExample1=tkinter.Text(frame_top, height=5)
textExample1.pack()
btnRead1=tkinter.Button(frame_top, height=1, width=10, text="Отправить", 
                    command=introductory_part)


# Описательная часть
frame_top = LabelFrame(text="Расскажите о своем опыте работы")
frame_top.pack()
textExample2=tkinter.Text(frame_top, height=5)
textExample2.pack()
btnRead2=tkinter.Button(frame_top, height=1, width=10, text="Отправить", 
                    command=descriptive_part)


# Резолютивная часть
frame_top = LabelFrame(text="Укажите свои лучшие качества")
frame_top.pack()
textExample3=tkinter.Text(frame_top, height=5)
textExample3.pack()
btnRead3=tkinter.Button(frame_top, height=1, width=10, text="Отправить", 
                    command=result_part)

btnRead1.pack()
btnRead2.pack()
btnRead3.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо!